# Chrome Extension | Couldn’t generate a file from a content script & Chrome GPUCache folder increase exponentially

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a chrome extension that depends on executing a content script that generates a text file of some content, and when loading the extension into Chrome browser as unpacked I found that the GPUCache folder which is located at the below path, keeps increasing exponentially with empty files.

> C:\Users<your username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User
> Data\GrShaderCache\GPUCache

Also, there are other problems that happen as long as the extension exists, I listed the problems I faced below

1. If you closed chrome then tried to open it normally, it wouldn't open unless you open the task manager then close all of its processes.
2. Downloading any file from the internet gives a "failed to download" error, and if you checked the "download path" you will find some arbitrary files have been downloaded.
3. Generating a text file from the content script is not working, although the code is working perfectly outside the extension. (see it below)

**Extension Code**

*manifest.json*

```
{
    "name": "My Extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "action": {
        "default_title": "Click to view a popup",
        "default_popup": "index.html"
    },
     "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "scripting",
        "tabs"
    ]
}
```

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>My Extension</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <style>
        body {
            min-width: 300px;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="card">
        <h5 class="card-header">My Extension <small>v1.0.0</small></h5>
        <div class="card-body text-center">
            <p class="card-text">Click "Start".</p>
            <input id="start" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Start" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

*index.js*

```
document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("click", start);

function start() {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
        var tab = tabs[0];
        chrome.scripting.executeScript({
            target: { tabId: tab.id },
            files: ['page.js'],
        });
    })
}
```

*page.js*

```
// this function is a proof of concept of what i intend to do
function download(filename, text) {
    var element = document.createElement('a');
    element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
    element.setAttribute('download', filename);

    element.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(element);

    element.click();

    document.body.removeChild(element);
}

download("hello.txt", "This is the content of my file :)");
```

My Chrome Version: 92.0.4515.107

Any idea why is that happening?

Comment: Chrome's handling of data URI when downloading is extremely inefficient as it decodes them in the main browser thread to a blob. Hence, you should just generate a blob yourself, then use URL.createObjectURL + revokeObjectURL.

Comment: you are right creating blobs from the data URI then using the temporary storage to download it is better, but you know it didn't work for me either. I just wanted my question to be specific for the above problems that make chrome doing unexpected things.

Comment: Do you know why GPUCache increases exponentially? I think it's the lost key of all problems I'm facing. @wOxxOm

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Chrome. Try sending the data in a message to the background script, and either move your download() function there or use `chrome.downloads` API.

Comment: I agree GPUCache problem is a bug in Chrome, my windows was having pending updates, after installing them the problem was gone.
and for the downloading thing, I tried that code on another machine with the same chrome version and it works fine, very strange.